# Excel vba add named range

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to add named range with VBA

```
Nname = "FindMe"
Formulas = "Vlookup(" & Chr(34) & Nname & Chr(34) & ";Translations!$A:$C;2;False)"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Nname, RefersToR1C1:=Formulas
```

But i get

> Vlookup(""FindMe"";Translations!$A:$C;2;False)

Instead of

> Vlookup("FindMe";Translations!$A:$C;2;False)

Why Excel put double qoutes? How to Get string which i want?

> Vlookup("FindMe";Translations!$A:$C;2;False)

Comment: as it looks right now to me, you can only set a range as it is as `RefersTo**`, formulas always pop up an error (at least for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string assigned to Formulas is missing an '=' at the beginning of the string. Thus, the name is being assigned a string constant instead of a formula. When you look in Name Manager dialog, you will that name FindMe refers to ="Vlookup(""FindMe"";Translations!$A:$C;2;False)". Note that two double quotes represents a single quote in a string constant.

If you add a '=' to the beginning of the string, then name will be assigned a formula. Also, the formula is using A1 notation but the VBA code is using RefersToR1C1. This will cause a formula parsing error. Either change the formula to R1C1 notation or change the VBA code to use RefersTo. For example...

```
Nname = "FindMe"
Formulas = "=Vlookup(" & Chr(34) & Nname & Chr(34) & ",Translations!$A:$C,2,False)"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Nname, RefersTo:=Formulas
```